Eventual equality of ranges of $(T-\lambda)^n$
Let $X$ be a Banach space, $T:X\to X$ a compact operator, and $\lambda$ a non-zero complex number.
I've shown that $(\operatorname{ran}((T-\lambda)^n)_{n<\infty}$ is an $\supseteq$-decreasing sequence of sets. Moreover, I've shown that there must be an eventual equality in these images via Riesz's Lemma.
However, I am unable to see why, if there exists $m$ such that $\operatorname{ran}(T-\lambda)^m = \operatorname{ran}(T-\lambda)^{m+1}$, then, for any $r > m$, we must have $\operatorname{ran}(T-\lambda)^r = \operatorname{ran}(T-\lambda)^m$.
This should be an easy proof by induction, but I cannot even prove the base case.
Assuming $\operatorname{ran}(T-\lambda)^m = \operatorname{ran}(T-\lambda)^{m+1}$, we show that $\operatorname{ran}(T-\lambda)^{m+1} \subset \operatorname{ran}(T-\lambda)^{m+2}$. Allow $x \in \operatorname{ran}(T-\lambda)^{m+1}$. Then, we can we find $x'$ such that $(T-\lambda)^{m+1}x' = x$. Moreover, I think we should be able to rewrite $(T-\lambda)^{m+2}$ in such a manner to apply our hypothesis, but I can't find a way.
Any tips are greatly appreciated.

$(T-\lambda)^{m}X=(T-\lambda)^{m+1}X$ implies $(T-\lambda)^{m+1}X=(T-\lambda)^{m+2}X$ by applying $T-\lambda$ to both sides. Hence $(T-\lambda)^{m}X=(T-\lambda)^{m+2}X.$

You can prove by induction that $\text{ran}(T-\lambda I)^{r} = \text{ran}(T - \lambda I)^{m}$ for all $r\in\mathbb{N}$ with $m \leq r$. The base case with $r = m$ is clearly satisfied. Now let $r\in\mathbb{N}$ with $m \leq r$ and suppose that $\text{ran}(T - \lambda I)^{r} = \text{ran}(T - \lambda I)^{m}$. By what you have already shown, it is sufficient to show that $\text{ran}(T - \lambda I)^{m} \subseteq \text{ran}(T - \lambda I)^{r+1}$. Let $x\in \text{ran}(T - \lambda I)^{m}$. As $\text{ran}(T-\lambda I)^{m} = \text{ran}(T-\lambda I)^{m+1}$ and as $\text{ran}(T-\lambda I)^{m+1} = (T-\lambda I)(\text{ran}(T-\lambda I)^{m})$, there is some $y\in \text{ran}(T-\lambda I)^{m}$ such that $(T-\lambda I)(y) = x$. By the inductive hypothesis, $y\in \text{ran}(T-\lambda I)^{r}$ and it follows that $x\in \text{ran}(T-\lambda I)^{r+1}$. The result follows by induction.

Thanks so much! I was getting unnecessarily confused yesterday.
